# Absolute position appearing differently in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I am using html5 boilerplate. The vimeo video appears to have different padding in different browser. What could be the solution?

Thanks

```
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body style="
  background: url(img/backround2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
">
<!--
Youtube
-->
<iframe style="position:absolute;margin-top:163px;margin-left:395px;" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?portrait=0&color=333" width="520px;" height="290px" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_counter_style" style="left:220px;top:150px;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="vertical"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="tall"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fe772f550658645"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which different browsers specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I checked the site with some versions of Chrome and Firefox and the results were different. So I am in a doubt if absolute positioning works differently on different broswers(due to their own standards issue.)

Comment: That sounds very unlikely. Modern browsers are pretty good at adhering to standards, and absolute positioning is a well established standard, so I can't imagine any reason why it would do that.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I wasnt having a positioned relative tag on the parent div. Thanks

Comment: okay, cool. If you've solved it, that's great. (post it as an answer and accept it :))

Answer (score 0):

The parent div should have to have.

```
position:relative
```

in order for

```
position:absolute
```

to work.